# Class name does not match path?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So I got:

```
class name (com/example/user/timetable_test/setup/SetTable$PlaceholderFragment) does not match path (com/example/user/timetable_test/setup/setTable$PlaceholderFragment.class)
```

I just made this activity and I am getting this error. I can see that there is a difference in the case, but I don't know how to fix this.

BTW, this is supposed to be tabbed activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just clean your project `Build --> Clean Project`

for more try in the following link

[Android studio gradle error with top-level exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674453/android-studio-gradle-error-with-top-level-exception)

Comment: The same happened to me but with a class' name. I refactored the class' name to match the path's case (because it was the correct one) and then it worked.